# Problem with stable input reading for HiFive 1 board in assembly

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am trying to write a program that will receive input from a button and turn on the on board LED. The thing works but not consistently. Sometimes after releasing the button the LED doesn't turn off.
Bellow is my code for a function that checks for the input logic. I am very confident that the rest of the program works fine. I have done the Blink program and it worked fine. I used functions from Blink to turn on the LED so its not an issue with LED. I tried internal pull up resistors, I also experimented with different values of pull down resistors. ranging from 1k-10k.

````
    .section .text
.align 2
.globl checkBot
#include "GPIO.inc"
#include "memoryMap.inc"

.equ ON, 0x1
.equ OFF, 0x0
checkBot:

addi sp, sp, -16
sw ra, 12(sp)

li t0, GPIO_CTRL_ADDR               # load GPIO base adress 
lw t1, GPIO_INPUT_VAL(t0)           # add the ofset for the READ register
li t2, PIN_2                        # load the BIT ofset of PIN2
and t2, t1, t2                      # and the READ register with the PIN2 ofset                    
beqz t2, pinOFF                     # if t2 is 0m then the READ register has 0 at the PIN2 ofset, branch to pinOFF
li a0, ON                           # return ON comand back to the main
j exit

pinOFF: 
li a0, OFF                          # return OFF comand back to the main 
j exit

exit:
lw ra, 12(sp)
addi sp, sp, 16
ret```
````

Comment: You might need [debouncing](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce).